# How to find all occurences of string (case-insensitive) in a file, python?

Tags: python

I have got the following code to find a string in a file and count the number of exact matches:

```
counter+=book.read().count(word)
```

What I'm trying to do is count the number of times the word (stored in the variable word – this is part of a for loop) appears, but case insensitivley.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Provide the for loop or provide more code so we can help.

Comment: Do you try `re` regex to count? I think it will be suitable for your condition.

Comment: I need to find many different words in the file (about 400,000), so I can't write a regex for each individual one unfortunatley.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert both strings to lower case:

```
counter+=book.read().lower().count(word.lower())
```

Comment: And naturally if you have 400,000 `word`s, don't do `book.read().lower()` for each of them :)

Comment: Should I just lowercase the whole file?